# Why does the value of an EditText (not null) always true?

Tags: java, android, null, android-edittext, equals

I have an `EditText` which, whenever I put it in an `if statement` with `!= null`, Android Studio warns me that the value will always be true.

I tried debugging and it advances to the `if block` even if I typed nothing in the `EditText`.

Here is an example:

```
EditText emailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profile_email_edit_text);

if (emailEditText.getText().toString() != null) {  // Android studio warning (Condition 'emailEditText.getText().toString() != null' is always 'true')

    Toast.makeText(this, "Not equal to null passed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // toast message appears when I try it
}
```

Note that if I use `.equals("")` instead, no problem happens.

Why does this happen?

Comment: why disliking I don't know what is the problem

Comment: EditText will always have some text, if none is entered then it will be emptry string "".

Comment: alright that helped post as an answer so that I one you up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`emailEditText.getText().toString()` will not return `null`. So there is no chance for NPE in following method. the `getText` will return **empty string** if there is *no* string, which is definitely not `null`

However the `EditText` itself can be `null` if *not* initialized properly!

So you can check weather it is empty or not and do your task!
You have many options..

```
emailEditText.getText().toString().matches("")

emailEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")

emailEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0

TextUtils.isEmpty( emailEditText.getText().toString()) // .toString(); is not required as @waqaslam pointed out
```

Comment: you don't need to call toString() on getText() when using TextItils.isEmpty

Comment: @waqaslam bah my bad ill update it thanks for sharing

Answer (score 3):

`EditText#getText` will never return a `null`, so the `Editable#toString` won't return a `null`.

It will return a `String` containing the characters that are in the `EditText`. If there are no characters, it'll return an empty `String`.

Empty `String` (`""`) isn't a `null`.

The interesting thing is, that if you try `EditText#setText(null)`, an empty `String` will be set.

Your condition should be `(!emailEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty())`

Answer (score 2):

`EditText` always return empty string instead of **null** even when called `setText(null)`.

Therefore, you should use `TextUtils.isEmpty()` to make your condition work.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an `EditText` it contains the string `""` by default. So when you give `edittext.getText().toString!=null` it returns `""` which is not `null`. Hence your `if` condition is always `true`.

Instead if you want it to be false for that condition use `if(edittext.getText().toString().equals(""))`.